# Braze on or what sort of clamp on a Cinelli frame?

Tags: derailleur, clamp

I'm seeing a ridiculously good local deal on a Cinelli Experience frame. I think I'll build it up with entry Campagnolo stuff (also seeing a deal). I am mildly confused about the front derailleur attachment. Some listings for the complete bike talk about it being braze-on, but I sure don't see that in pictures: I see some sort of Cinelli specific clamp. Is a normal 35mm Campagnolo clamp front derailleur just fine? What is this?

[image]

Comment: Not really related, but if the price is suspiciously low, note that making fake frames is becoming more and more common.

Comment: Just my expenience, but braze-on front mechs aren't held as firmly as band on ones.  My seatpost is not round so a band-on one is impossible.
Also be aware of the crush limits of a modern frame - you don't want to tighten fittings with a gorilla-arm force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cinelli spec for this bike lists it as "clamp on" and your picture definitely shows a clamp on style front derailleur.

While it does seem like the factory build comes with a Cinelli branded clamp, if the frame you are buying is missing that part, you shouldn't have any trouble with a campy clamp, like this one:

[image]

If you are buying a a new campy gruppo, make sure you get the clamp on style front derailleur.  You can find just this part as well on ebay or an online parts supplier.  There are also adapters for braze on to clamp on style derailleurs, in case you found a good deal on a used campy gruppo with braze on front derailleur.

Comment: Take a close look at the picture, the bike already appears to come with a Cinelli branded braze on to clamp adapter.  So both descriptions are in a sense correct.

Comment: @Rider_X I wasn't sure if the photo was the actual bike he is buying or just a photo of that model. If he's buying a bare frame it may well not come with that clamp.